# How to mount an NZXT Kraken in a CoolerMaster MasterCase Pro 5

Tags: cpu-cooler, water-cooling

I have been trying to build my new system, and the water cooler that I ordered, the NZXT Kraken x61, does not seem to fit anywhere in the case because it is too long. I tried mounting it in the front rather than in the top, but the screws that I have are not long enough for mounting in the front. I also tried mounting it using the method shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXfeQ-RkHQ4&ab_channel=CoolerMaster. I would really like to be able to use this water cooler, but I can't see how to mount it in the case.

Comment: Sorry i'm so late to notice this post, is it still an issue?

Comment: Well, I still have the radiator, so sort of. I got another one, and I just haven't sold the old one yet. But out of curiosity, would you be able to mount it? I tried top mounted (end tank makes it too long), and I couldn't figure out front mounted.

Comment: You said in your original post that the screws were not long enough to mount the radiator. Why was this? 
The usual way a radiator is mounted is using 6 or 8 small screws to secure the radiator to the frame of the computer, and then another 8 screws to secure the fans to the opposite side. 
Alternatively, you can use long screws that go through the case and fan and screw into the radiator, securing it.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick search on youtube showed this guy has the x62 which i think is the same size? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tn8zQRBM86Y

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.